# preload/show data in CNContactViewController (swift)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, cncontact

Could we show data in ios editor/CNContactViewController instead only show blank textfields?

for example, when I open CNContactViewController I want the name to be filled before user type anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. Using  viewControllerForNewContact: method of CNContactViewController, you can pass a CNContact object.

So in order to show name as filled in view, create a contact object with name and pass to viewControllerForNewContact:

```
CNMutableContact *pNewContact          = [[CNMutableContact alloc] init];
pNewContact.givenName                  = @"My Name";
CNContactViewController *pNewContactVC = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForNewContact:pNewContact];
UINavigationController *pNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pNewContactVC];
[self presentViewController:pNavController animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

Please see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CNContactViewController/viewControllerForNewContact:

Comment: how to make a CNContact object? As I know I could only create a new contact using CNMutableContact, save it to contacts, and I need to fetch it from contacts so I got the CNContact object. Is there anyway that I could do that without adding the data to contact first? @Annie

Comment: Oh, for a new contact  (without saving and refetching), have you tried + viewControllerForUnknownContact:

Comment: I kinda confused, if we use CNviewcontroller for get CNContact object so user need to type the name etc first but the main goal is to filled the name's textfield before user type anything @Annie

Comment: Please see the updated answer with example for a new contact with name field filled. Here before user types anything the name field will show as "My Name" . Is that the case you were telling @Aldo